# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Tags: java, windows

Can anyone help me to get rid of this `Exception`?

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10"

```
import java.util.*;
public class AscendingOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i, j, temp;
        int a[] = {
            10, 5, 7, 98, 45, 34, 38, 56, 34, 93
        };

        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < a.length - 1; j++) {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception in last statement-

> System.out.println(a[i]);

This is not printing your whole array but the 11th index of your array which is not there.
So you are getting exception. 
Because when for loop ends then i value increment by 1.

Try with

> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

Answer (score 1):

Because at `System.out.println(a[i]);` `i` is equal to `a.length` (per the for loop condition), also you had your loop conditions swapped

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
    if (a[i] > a[j]) {
      temp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // <-- print the entire array
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = {10, 5, 7, 98, 45, 34, 38, 56, 34, 93};
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length -1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(a[k]);

    }
}
```

You can prevent those exceptions declaring variables inside the for loop .

eg: `for (int i = 0; i < a.length -1; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

It's the last statement.
Change it in

```
 System.out.println(a[i-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class. There is a nice method in there that you might find useful: sort(int[])

*-Thomas*

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class AscendingOrder {
   public static void  main(String[] args) {

```
int i,j,temp ;      
int a[]={10,5,7,98,45,34,38,56, 34,93};

for ( i=0; i<a.length;i++){         
    for (j=i+1; j<a.length-1;j++){              
        if( a[i] > a[j]){                   
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;                  
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As Tarun said, the problem is in your last 'println' statement.

When your i=9 iteration ends, the 'i++' term makes your variable i increment and have value 10. Sure, you never enter the loop, but you're still trying to print i[10]. This is out of bounds for your array which extends from i[0] to i[9].

Answer (score 0):

Print your `array a` object using `Arrays utility`.

**Program:**

```
public class TestArray {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int i, j, temp;
            int a[] = {
                10, 5, 7, 98, 45, 34, 38, 56, 34, 93
            };

            for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (j = i + 1; j < a.length - 1; j++) {
                    if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                        temp = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = temp;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[5, 7, 10, 45, 34, 38, 56, 34, 98, 93]
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey As per your code when you try to print

System.out.println(a[i]);

it will throw exception. You should focus on value of i.
When your loop is terminate the value of i = Length of array + 1.

So i recommend you should print

System.out.println(a[i-1]);

You can learn more about exception handling from here
http://java2all.com/technology/core-java/exception-handling/introduction

and learn about thread from here
http://java2all.com/technology/core-java/multithreading